# Invalid argument passed to lookupTransform

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a `ray_ground_filter` node from Autoware.ai. I am get the following error when I launch the node.

```
Invalid argument passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty
```

I noticed that my `tf_static` is empty for some odd reason.Could anyone help me in understanding this bug?

**ray_ground_filter.cpp**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2017-2019 Autoware Foundation. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 ********************
 *  v1.0: amc-nu (abrahammonrroy@yahoo.com)
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl_ros/transforms.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d_omp.h>
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
#include <velodyne_pointcloud/point_types.h>
#include "autoware_config_msgs/ConfigRayGroundFilter.h"

#include <opencv2/core/version.hpp>
#if (CV_MAJOR_VERSION == 3)
#include "gencolors.cpp"
#else
#include <opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>
#endif

#include "points_preprocessor/ray_ground_filter/ray_ground_filter.h"

void RayGroundFilter::update_config_params(const autoware_config_msgs::ConfigRayGroundFilter::ConstPtr& param)
{
  general_max_slope_ = param->general_max_slope;
  local_max_slope_ = param->local_max_slope;
  radial_divider_angle_ = param->radial_divider_angle;
  concentric_divider_distance_ = param->concentric_divider_distance;
  min_height_threshold_ = param->min_height_threshold;
  clipping_height_ = param->clipping_height;
  min_point_distance_ = param->min_point_distance;
  reclass_distance_threshold_ = param->reclass_distance_threshold;
}

bool RayGroundFilter::TransformPointCloud(const std::string& in_target_frame,
                                          const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& in_cloud_ptr,
                                          const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::Ptr& out_cloud_ptr)
{
  if (in_target_frame == in_cloud_ptr->header.frame_id)
  {
    *out_cloud_ptr = *in_cloud_ptr;
    return true;
  }

  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transform_stamped;
  try
  {
    transform_stamped = tf_buffer_.lookupTransform(in_target_frame, in_cloud_ptr->header.frame_id,
                                                   in_cloud_ptr->header.stamp, ros::Duration(1.0));
  }
  catch (tf2::TransformException& ex)
  {
    ROS_WARN("%s", ex.what());
    return false;
  }
  // tf2::doTransform(*in_cloud_ptr, *out_cloud_ptr, transform_stamped);
  Eigen::Matrix4f mat = tf2::transformToEigen(transform_stamped.transform).matrix().cast<float>();
  pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(mat, *in_cloud_ptr, *out_cloud_ptr);
  out_cloud_ptr->header.frame_id = in_target_frame;
  return true;
}

void RayGroundFilter::publish_cloud(const ros::Publisher& in_publisher,
                                    const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr in_cloud_to_publish_ptr,
                                    const std_msgs::Header& in_header)
{
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::Ptr cloud_msg_ptr(new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2);
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::Ptr trans_cloud_msg_ptr(new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2);
  pcl::toROSMsg(*in_cloud_to_publish_ptr, *cloud_msg_ptr);
  cloud_msg_ptr->header.frame_id = base_frame_;
  cloud_msg_ptr->header.stamp = in_header.stamp;
  const bool succeeded = TransformPointCloud(in_header.frame_id, cloud_msg_ptr, trans_cloud_msg_ptr);
  if (!succeeded)
  {
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM_THROTTLE(10, "Failed transform from " << cloud_msg_ptr->header.frame_id << " to "
                                                           << in_header.frame_id);
    return;
  }
  in_publisher.publish(*trans_cloud_msg_ptr);
}

/*!
 *
 * @param[in] in_cloud Input Point Cloud to be organized in radial segments
 * @param[out] out_organized_points Custom Point Cloud filled with XYZRTZColor data
 * @param[out] out_radial_divided_indices Indices of the points in the original cloud for each radial segment
 * @param[out] out_radial_ordered_clouds Vector of Points Clouds, each element will contain the points ordered
 */
void RayGroundFilter::ConvertXYZIToRTZColor(
    const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr in_cloud,
    const std::shared_ptr<PointCloudXYZIRTColor>& out_organized_points,
    const std::shared_ptr<std::vector<pcl::PointIndices> >& out_radial_divided_indices,
    const std::shared_ptr<std::vector<PointCloudXYZIRTColor> >& out_radial_ordered_clouds)
{
  out_organized_points->resize(in_cloud->points.size());
  out_radial_divided_indices->clear();
  out_radial_divided_indices->resize(radial_dividers_num_);
  out_radial_ordered_clouds->resize(radial_dividers_num_);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < in_cloud->points.size(); i++)
  {
    PointXYZIRTColor new_point;
    auto radius = static_cast<float>(
        sqrt(in_cloud->points[i].x * in_cloud->points[i].x + in_cloud->points[i].y * in_cloud->points[i].y));
    auto theta = static_cast<float>(atan2(in_cloud->points[i].y, in_cloud->points[i].x) * 180 / M_PI);
    if (theta < 0)
    {
      theta += 360;
    }
    if (theta >= 360)
    {
      theta -= 360;
    }

    auto radial_div = (size_t)floor(theta / radial_divider_angle_);

    auto concentric_div = (size_t)floor(fabs(radius / concentric_divider_distance_));

    new_point.point = in_cloud->points[i];
    new_point.radius = radius;
    new_point.theta = theta;
    new_point.radial_div = radial_div;
    new_point.concentric_div = concentric_div;
    new_point.red = (size_t)colors_[new_point.radial_div % color_num_].val[0];
    new_point.green = (size_t)colors_[new_point.radial_div % color_num_].val[1];
    new_point.blue = (size_t)colors_[new_point.radial_div % color_num_].val[2];
    new_point.original_index = i;

    out_organized_points->at(i) = new_point;

    // radial divisions
    out_radial_divided_indices->at(radial_div).indices.push_back(i);

    out_radial_ordered_clouds->at(radial_div).push_back(new_point);
  }  // end for

// order radial points on each division
#pragma omp for
  for (size_t i = 0; i < radial_dividers_num_; i++)
  {
    std::sort(out_radial_ordered_clouds->at(i).begin(), out_radial_ordered_clouds->at(i).end(),
              [](const PointXYZIRTColor& a, const PointXYZIRTColor& b) { return a.radius < b.radius; });  // NOLINT
  }
}

/*!
 * Classifies Points in the PointCoud as Ground and Not Ground
 * @param in_radial_ordered_clouds Vector of an Ordered PointsCloud ordered by radial distance from the origin
 * @param out_ground_indices Returns the indices of the points classified as ground in the original PointCloud
 * @param out_no_ground_indices Returns the indices of the points classified as not ground in the original PointCloud
 */
void RayGroundFilter::ClassifyPointCloud(const std::vector<PointCloudXYZIRTColor>& in_radial_ordered_clouds,
                                         const pcl::PointIndices::Ptr& out_ground_indices,
                                         const pcl::PointIndices::Ptr& out_no_ground_indices)
{
  out_ground_indices->indices.clear();
  out_no_ground_indices->indices.clear();
#pragma omp for
  for (size_t i = 0; i < in_radial_ordered_clouds.size(); i++)  // sweep through each radial division
  {
    float prev_radius = 0.f;
    float prev_height = 0.f;
    bool prev_ground = false;
    bool current_ground = false;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < in_radial_ordered_clouds[i].size(); j++)  // loop through each point in the radial div
    {
      float points_distance = in_radial_ordered_clouds[i][j].radius - prev_radius;
      float height_threshold = tan(DEG2RAD(local_max_slope_)) * points_distance;
      float current_height = in_radial_ordered_clouds[i][j].point.z;
      float general_height_threshold = tan(DEG2RAD(general_max_slope_)) * in_radial_ordered_clouds[i][j].radius;

      // for points which are very close causing the height threshold to be tiny, set a minimum value
      if (points_distance > concentric_divider_distance_ && height_threshold < min_height_threshold_)
      {
        height_threshold = min_height_threshold_;
      }

      // check current point height against the LOCAL threshold (previous point)
      if (current_height <= (prev_height + height_threshold) && current_height >= (prev_height - height_threshold))
      {
        // Check again using general geometry (radius from origin) if previous points wasn't ground
        if (!prev_ground)
        {
          if (current_height <= general_height_threshold && current_height >= -general_height_threshold)
          {
            current_ground = true;
          }
          else
          {
            current_ground = false;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          current_ground = true;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        // check if previous point is too far from previous one, if so classify again
        if (points_distance > reclass_distance_threshold_ &&
            (current_height <= height_threshold && current_height >= -height_threshold))
        {
          current_ground = true;
        }
        else
        {
          current_ground = false;
        }
      }

      if (current_ground)
      {
        out_ground_indices->indices.push_back(in_radial_ordered_clouds[i][j].original_index);
        prev_ground = true;
      }
      else
      {
        out_no_ground_indices->indices.push_back(in_radial_ordered_clouds[i][j].original_index);
        prev_ground = false;
      }

      prev_radius = in_radial_ordered_clouds[i][j].radius;
      prev_height = in_radial_ordered_clouds[i][j].point.z;
    }
  }
}

/*!
 * Removes the points higher than a threshold
 * @param in_cloud_ptr PointCloud to perform Clipping
 * @param in_clip_height Maximum allowed height in the cloud
 * @param out_clipped_cloud_ptr Resultung PointCloud with the points removed
 */
void RayGroundFilter::ClipCloud(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr in_cloud_ptr, const double in_clip_height,
                                pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr out_clipped_cloud_ptr)
{
  pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZI> extractor;
  extractor.setInputCloud(in_cloud_ptr);
  pcl::PointIndices indices;

#pragma omp for
  for (size_t i = 0; i < in_cloud_ptr->points.size(); i++)
  {
    if (in_cloud_ptr->points[i].z > in_clip_height)
    {
      indices.indices.push_back(i);
    }
  }
  extractor.setIndices(boost::make_shared<pcl::PointIndices>(indices));
  extractor.setNegative(true);  // true removes the indices, false leaves only the indices
  extractor.filter(*out_clipped_cloud_ptr);
}

/*!
 * Returns the resulting complementary PointCloud, one with the points kept and the other removed as indicated
 * in the indices
 * @param in_cloud_ptr Input PointCloud to which the extraction will be performed
 * @param in_indices Indices of the points to be both removed and kept
 * @param out_only_indices_cloud_ptr Resulting PointCloud with the indices kept
 * @param out_removed_indices_cloud_ptr Resulting PointCloud with the indices removed
 */
void RayGroundFilter::ExtractPointsIndices(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr in_cloud_ptr,
                                           const pcl::PointIndices& in_indices,
                                           pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr out_only_indices_cloud_ptr,
                                           pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr out_removed_indices_cloud_ptr)
{
  pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZI> extract_ground;
  extract_ground.setInputCloud(in_cloud_ptr);
  extract_ground.setIndices(boost::make_shared<pcl::PointIndices>(in_indices));

  extract_ground.setNegative(false);  // true removes the indices, false leaves only the indices
  extract_ground.filter(*out_only_indices_cloud_ptr);

  extract_ground.setNegative(true);  // true removes the indices, false leaves only the indices
  extract_ground.filter(*out_removed_indices_cloud_ptr);
}

/*!
 * Removes points up to a certain distance in the XY Plane
 * @param in_cloud_ptr Input PointCloud
 * @param in_min_distance Minimum valid distance, points closer than this will be removed.
 * @param out_filtered_cloud_ptr Resulting PointCloud with the invalid points removed.
 */
void RayGroundFilter::RemovePointsUpTo(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr in_cloud_ptr, double in_min_distance,
                                       pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr out_filtered_cloud_ptr)
{
  pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZI> extractor;
  extractor.setInputCloud(in_cloud_ptr);
  pcl::PointIndices indices;

#pragma omp for
  for (size_t i = 0; i < in_cloud_ptr->points.size(); i++)
  {
    if (sqrt(in_cloud_ptr->points[i].x * in_cloud_ptr->points[i].x +
             in_cloud_ptr->points[i].y * in_cloud_ptr->points[i].y) < in_min_distance)
    {
      indices.indices.push_back(i);
    }
  }
  extractor.setIndices(boost::make_shared<pcl::PointIndices>(indices));
  extractor.setNegative(true);  // true removes the indices, false leaves only the indices
  extractor.filter(*out_filtered_cloud_ptr);
}

void RayGroundFilter::CloudCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& in_sensor_cloud)
{
  health_checker_ptr_->NODE_ACTIVATE();
  health_checker_ptr_->CHECK_RATE("topic_rate_points_raw_slow", 8, 5, 1, "topic points_raw subscribe rate slow.");

  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::Ptr trans_sensor_cloud(new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2);
  const bool succeeded = TransformPointCloud(base_frame_, in_sensor_cloud, trans_sensor_cloud);
  if (!succeeded)
  {
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM_THROTTLE(10, "Failed transform from " << base_frame_ << " to "
                                                           << in_sensor_cloud->header.frame_id);
    return;
  }

  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr current_sensor_cloud_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
  pcl::fromROSMsg(*trans_sensor_cloud, *current_sensor_cloud_ptr);

  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr clipped_cloud_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);

  // remove points above certain point
  ClipCloud(current_sensor_cloud_ptr, clipping_height_, clipped_cloud_ptr);

  // remove closer points than a threshold
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr filtered_cloud_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
  RemovePointsUpTo(clipped_cloud_ptr, min_point_distance_, filtered_cloud_ptr);

  // GetCloud Normals
  // pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZINormal>::Ptr cloud_with_normals_ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZINormal>);
  // GetCloudNormals(current_sensor_cloud_ptr, cloud_with_normals_ptr, 5.0);

  std::shared_ptr<PointCloudXYZIRTColor> organized_points(new PointCloudXYZIRTColor);
  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<pcl::PointIndices> > radial_division_indices(new std::vector<pcl::PointIndices>);
  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<PointCloudXYZIRTColor> > radial_ordered_clouds(new std::vector<PointCloudXYZIRTColor>);

  radial_dividers_num_ = ceil(360 / radial_divider_angle_);

  ConvertXYZIToRTZColor(filtered_cloud_ptr, organized_points, radial_division_indices, radial_ordered_clouds);

  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr ground_indices(new pcl::PointIndices), no_ground_indices(new pcl::PointIndices);

  ClassifyPointCloud(*radial_ordered_clouds, ground_indices, no_ground_indices);

  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr ground_cloud_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr no_ground_cloud_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);

  ExtractPointsIndices(filtered_cloud_ptr, *ground_indices, ground_cloud_ptr, no_ground_cloud_ptr);

  publish_cloud(ground_points_pub_, ground_cloud_ptr, in_sensor_cloud->header);
  publish_cloud(groundless_points_pub_, no_ground_cloud_ptr, in_sensor_cloud->header);
}

RayGroundFilter::RayGroundFilter() : node_handle_("~"), tf_listener_(tf_buffer_)

{
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::NodeHandle pnh("~");
  health_checker_ptr_ = std::make_shared<autoware_health_checker::HealthChecker>(nh, pnh);
  health_checker_ptr_->ENABLE();
}

void RayGroundFilter::Run()
{
  // Model   |   Horizontal   |   Vertical   | FOV(Vertical)    degrees / rads
  // ----------------------------------------------------------
  // HDL-64  |0.08-0.35(0.32) |     0.4      |  -24.9 <=x<=2.0   (26.9  / 0.47)
  // HDL-32  |     0.1-0.4    |     1.33     |  -30.67<=x<=10.67 (41.33 / 0.72)
  // VLP-16  |     0.1-0.4    |     2.0      |  -15.0<=x<=15.0   (30    / 0.52)
  // VLP-16HD|     0.1-0.4    |     1.33     |  -10.0<=x<=10.0   (20    / 0.35)
  ROS_INFO("Initializing Ground Filter, please wait...");
  node_handle_.param<std::string>("input_point_topic", input_point_topic_, "/points_raw");
  ROS_INFO("Input point_topic: %s", input_point_topic_.c_str());

  node_handle_.param<std::string>("base_frame", base_frame_, "base_link");
  ROS_INFO("base_frame: %s", base_frame_.c_str());

  node_handle_.param("general_max_slope", general_max_slope_, 3.0);
  ROS_INFO("general_max_slope[deg]: %f", general_max_slope_);

  node_handle_.param("local_max_slope", local_max_slope_, 5.0);
  ROS_INFO("local_max_slope[deg]: %f", local_max_slope_);

  node_handle_.param("radial_divider_angle", radial_divider_angle_, 0.1);  // 1 degree default
  ROS_INFO("radial_divider_angle[deg]: %f", radial_divider_angle_);
  node_handle_.param("concentric_divider_distance", concentric_divider_distance_, 0.0);  // 0.0 meters default
  ROS_INFO("concentric_divider_distance[meters]: %f", concentric_divider_distance_);
  node_handle_.param("min_height_threshold", min_height_threshold_, 0.05);  // 0.05 meters default
  ROS_INFO("min_height_threshold[meters]: %f", min_height_threshold_);
  node_handle_.param("clipping_height", clipping_height_, 2.0);  // 2.0 meters default above the car
  ROS_INFO("clipping_height[meters]: %f", clipping_height_);
  node_handle_.param("min_point_distance", min_point_distance_, 1.85);  // 1.85 meters default
  ROS_INFO("min_point_distance[meters]: %f", min_point_distance_);
  node_handle_.param("reclass_distance_threshold", reclass_distance_threshold_, 0.2);  // 0.5 meters default
  ROS_INFO("reclass_distance_threshold[meters]: %f", reclass_distance_threshold_);

#if (CV_MAJOR_VERSION == 3)
  generateColors(colors_, color_num_);
#else
  cv::generateColors(colors_, color_num_);
#endif

  radial_dividers_num_ = ceil(360 / radial_divider_angle_);
  ROS_INFO("Radial Divisions: %d", (int)radial_dividers_num_);

  std::string no_ground_topic, ground_topic;
  node_handle_.param<std::string>("no_ground_point_topic", no_ground_topic, "/points_no_ground");
  ROS_INFO("No Ground Output Point Cloud no_ground_point_topic: %s", no_ground_topic.c_str());
  node_handle_.param<std::string>("ground_point_topic", ground_topic, "/points_ground");
  ROS_INFO("Only Ground Output Point Cloud ground_topic: %s", ground_topic.c_str());

  ROS_INFO("Subscribing to... %s", input_point_topic_.c_str());
  points_node_sub_ = node_handle_.subscribe(input_point_topic_, 1, &RayGroundFilter::CloudCallback, this);

  config_node_sub_ =
      node_handle_.subscribe("/config/ray_ground_filter", 1, &RayGroundFilter::update_config_params, this);

  groundless_points_pub_ = node_handle_.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>(no_ground_topic, 2);
  ground_points_pub_ = node_handle_.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>(ground_topic, 2);

  ROS_INFO("Ready");

  ros::spin();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406406/invalid-argument-passed-to-lookuptransform/) by [Junaid22](https://answers.ros.org/users/108218/junaid22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the following line taken from the above code:

```
transform_stamped = tf_buffer_.lookupTransform(in_target_frame, in_cloud_ptr->header.frame_id,
                                               in_cloud_ptr->header.stamp, ros::Duration(1.0));
```

The error you are receiving is due to empty target frame, i.e., `in_target_frame`. Therefore, please run a debugger or add a print statement to confirm its value.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Junaid22](https://answers.ros.org/users/108218/junaid22/) on 2022-09-14**:
I did print out the `in_target_frame`. I got two log files which are here.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qsjc9dXfiTE78cKTeJ7ElmE9O4hTFkvT/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18lXeNC71Ad2A2DlEwrOgccMDIJk_jrjL/view?usp=sharing

I didnt get any warning or error either.

**Comment by [Junaid22](https://answers.ros.org/users/108218/junaid22/) on 2022-09-14**:
I have sorted it out. Thanks for the help @ravijoshi

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-14**:
I am glad you made it work. If this answer helped you, please upvote and accept it by marking it as the correct answer.

**Comment by [Junaid22](https://answers.ros.org/users/108218/junaid22/) on 2022-09-15**:
ok @ravijoshi.
Thanks